# Possible to pass result of SQL query into next SQL query

Tags: android, sql

I'm just wondering if it's possible

for example I have a query

```
 query = String.format("SELECT * FROM assetParamater LEFT OUTER JOIN SpecialOffer USING (assetID) WHERE assetParameter.assetID = %d;", id);
```

So that all looks good, but the issue is that id, is actually the special offer id and not the assetId.

So I need to for example pass the result of this query

```
QUERY RESULT = "Select assetID from assetParameter where SpecialOffer.specialOfferID = %id;", id);

query = String.format("SELECT * FROM assetParamater LEFT OUTER JOIN SpecialOffer USING (assetID) WHERE assetParameter.assetID = %d;", QUERY RESULT);
```

Does anyone know the method of how to do this?  I appreciate that it's not exactly the cleanest way of doing it but I'm stuck with the special offer id being passed in as id so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your table structure isn't clear... in your second query you refer to the SpecialOffer table without using it in the FROM clause...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's wrong with just a regular join in this case?

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
  FROM assetParameter 
  JOIN SpecialOffer 
    ON assetParameter.assetID = SpecialOffer.assetID
 WHERE SpecialOffer.specialOfferID = %id
```

Don't use `SELECT *` by the way - better to specify the columns you need.

You can also use a subquery if you only want to query data from the assetParameter table...

```
SELECT Column1, Column2
  FROM assetParameter 
 WHERE assetID = (select assetID
                    from SpecialOffer 
                       WHERE SpecialOffer.specialOfferID = %id)
```